# Where is my ios simulator?

Tags: ios

I used to have all simulators like `iphone4` and `iPad` before. I noticed that only `iPhone6` and `iPhone5s` are available. **`Other simulators are not available any longer.`** I have no idea what I have done. please suggest me what should i do for this ?

Comment: You might have upgraded your Xcode version.

Open Xcode, choose the Xcode option on the window bar, and go Preferences -> Downloads. See if there are any simulators to download there.

Comment: Make new simulators in the Devices window.

Answer (score 0):

1) Update your Xcode (AppStore > Updates > Xcode)
2) Open Xcode
3) Go to the menu Xcode > Settings > Downloads
4) In the upper half of the window you can now download components like that:

[image]

5) Once you downloaded the simulator you are looking for make sure that:

- Your Project Build Target matches the simulator version you want to test (e.g. iOS8 as build target will only allow for iPad, iPhone 6, 6Plus & iPhone 5S/5, iPhone 4S - not older devices.